# “Who’s volunteer” or “who’s a volunteer” or ...?

Tags: articles, expression-choice

in a classroom, a teacher wants to see who in the class is willing to come for a short presentation. Which of the following should the teacher say?

> Who’s volunteer?
>
> Who’s a volunteer?
>
> Who’s volunteering?
>
> Who can volunteer?

Which version is correct and which is wrong?

Comment: Probably: *Student, it's your turn*. ;)  Seriously, *Who would like to volunteer?* is a polite way to ask.

Comment: What Clare said -- "Who would like to volunteer?"  "Whose volunteer?" (which is pronounced identically to "Who's volunteer?") would be asking who the volunteer belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in the first three sentences, "Who's" is a contraction of "Who is". Try expanding the sentences and see whether that makes things any clearer to you:

Who is volunteer?

Who is a volunteer?

Who is volunteering?

Who can volunteer?

The first one is ungrammatical. You can't have a count noun (a noun used in the singular and in the plural) unpreceded by an article or possessive adjective. The second one is grammatical, but not correct in this context. The third one is borderline correct (with the present tense serving to indicate the future). But the fourth is by far the best of the options you have presented. The question is best expressed as "Who is capable of volunteering?" or "Who will volunteer?" Your fourth sentence matches the first of those two possibilities.